# usage of "later on" and "later"

Tags: word-choice

It will be communicated to you later.

or

It will be communicated to you later on.

Please tell me which is correct or better expression.

Comment: They both mean largely the same thing, so I'd recommend the simpler approach: "It will be communicated to you later."

Answer (score 1):

Either is acceptable. English has a lot of flexibility. If it's a straightforward situation you should probably choose the simpler one, meaning drop the "on." So in a business memo or in a simple conversation or other such situation you would drop the "on."

If you were writing poetry you might include it to add a syllable or to get your rhyme *on*.

Or if you were trying to be extra emphatic, such as if somebody asked you the same question three times and you wanted them to pay attention.

"What is the arrangement for getting stationery?"
"That will be communicated to you later."
"But if I need some stationery, where do I get it?"
"That will be communicated to you later."
"Can't you tell me where to get stationery?"
"That *will* be communicated to you later *on*."